# AWS CloudFormation: API Gateway File Size Exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, aws-cloudformation-macro

I have my OpenAPI spec stored in s3 and I am currently currently using the template shown below in my CloudFormation code:

```yaml
  RestAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Condition: NeedsRestApi
    DependsOn: [A, B]
    Properties:
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Body:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location:
              Fn::Sub: s3://${bucket}/${env}/application/temp-service/api_gateway.yaml
```

When I try to deploy it in CloudFormation, it complains about the Api Gateway size being larger than `AWS:Include` supports (450 KB):

> Transform AWS::Include failed with: The specified S3 object is too big.

I also tried using `BodyS3LocationApproach` without using `AWS::Include`:

```
      BodyS3Location:
        Bucket:
          Fn::Sub: ${bucket}
        Key:
          Fn::Sub: ${env}/application/temp-service/api_gateway.yaml
```

However, the above approach generates an error since my `api_gateway.yaml` content has some dynamic values which will be populated on the fly in CloudFormation:

> Resource handler returned message: "Invalid OpenAPI input. (Service: ApiGateway,

Can you please suggest correct and alternative way of loading my big api_gateway file into CloudFormation template and create the RESTAPI resource and deploy respective rest api(s) the AWS api-gateway?

Comment: General advice at [AWS CloudFormation quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) for template size exceeded is to divide into smaller, nested stacks or use minification. Is this a single Rest API? 450 KB seems quite large.

Comment: Yes its a single REST file which exceeds 450 KB . Now What should i do , Can you elaborate your suggestion plz

Comment: It looks like AWS [increased some CF quotas](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-increased-limits-on-five-service-quotas/) in 2022 including the maximum size of a template that can be passed in an S3 Object is now 1MB (previously 450KB). I'm wondering if they didn't apply that same increase in the specific case you're running into, but perhaps should have done so. I'd consider raising a support ticket with AWS for this.

Comment: @jarmod Did you raise support ticket for this . Can you post the link so that i can track of

Comment: I did not. The comment "I'd consider raising a support ticket with AWS for this" was a suggestion to you to raise a support ticket if this is important to you.